# Google Analytics Custom Variable only Tracks Last Key

Tags: google-analytics

I've got some experience with GA and custom variables, and code that I don't think was changed stopped working yesterday.  It's straightforward, and this is the exact code that runs on the site (minus the UA code and domain.)  Strangely, GA is now ONLY taking the last variable that is set in a particular slot.

I've got this code:

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxx']);
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',2,'test1','testvalue1',2]);
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',2,'test2','testvalue2',2]);
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',2,'test3','testvalue3',2]);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
 var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
 ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
 var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```

Which should track four custom variables in GA.  However, only the FINAL variable is getting tracked.  Here's the output:

```
_gaq.push processing "_setAccount" for args: "[UA-18327050-3]":  ga_debug.js:24
_gaq.push processing "_setCustomVar" for args: "[2,test1,testvalue1,2]":  ga_debug.js:24
_gaq.push processing "_setCustomVar" for args: "[2,test2,testvalue2,2]":  ga_debug.js:24
_gaq.push processing "_setCustomVar" for args: "[2,test3,testvalue3,2]":  ga_debug.js:24
_gaq.push processing "_trackPageview" for args: "[]":  ga_debug.js:24
Track Pageview ga_debug.js:24
Tracking beacon sent!
utmwv=5.4.7d&utms=108&utmn=1896343294&utmhn=xxxdomain.com&utme=8(2!test3)9(2!testvalue3)11(2!2)&utmcs=ISO-8859-1&utmsr=1366x768&utmvp=1366x46&utmsc=24-bit&utmul=en-us&utmje=1&utmfl=12.0%20r0&utmhid=1416834004&utmr=-&utmp=%2Ftest.php&utmht=1393527804008&utmac=UA-18327050-3&utmcc=__utma%3D211559050.1602513162.1393521508.1393521508.1393521508.1%3B%2B__utmz%3D211559050.1393521508.1.1.utmcsr%3D(direct)%7Cutmccn%3D(direct)%7Cutmcmd%3D(none)%3B&utmu=qQ~ ga_debug.js:24
Account ID               : UA-xxx-3
Host Name                : xxxdomain.com
Page                     : /test.php
Referring URL            : -
Hit ID                   : 1416834004
Visitor ID               : 1602513162
Session Count            : 1
Session Time - First     : Thu Feb 27 2014 07:18:28 GMT-1000 (Hawaiian Standard Time)
Session Time - Last      : Thu Feb 27 2014 07:18:28 GMT-1000 (Hawaiian Standard Time)
Session Time - Current   : Thu Feb 27 2014 07:18:28 GMT-1000 (Hawaiian Standard Time)
Campaign Time            : Thu Feb 27 2014 07:18:28 GMT-1000 (Hawaiian Standard Time)
Campaign Session         : 1
Campaign Count           : 1
Campaign Source          : (direct)
Campaign Medium          : (none);
Campaign Name            : (direct)
Custom Var 2             : label:'test3' value:'testvalue3' scope:'2'
Language                 : en-us
Encoding                 : ISO-8859-1
Flash Version            : 12.0 r0
Java Enabled             : true
Screen Resolution        : 1366x768
Browser Size             : 1366x46
Color Depth              : 24-bit
Ga.js Version            : 5.4.7d
Cachebuster              : 1896343294
```

Answer (score 2):

Each custom variable you're setting has the index of 2. Use your other indices, such as 1,3,4, or 5.

For example:

```
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',1,'test1','testvalue1',2]);
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',2,'test2','testvalue2',2]);
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',3,'test3','testvalue3',2]);
```